# Convert Airy Integral to cosine integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, airy-functions

I'm doing some research on the Airy function and its derivation and I am confused on how to arrive from the Airy function to Jeffrey's form, as is presented in his paper [The Effect of Love Waves of Heterogeneity in the Lower Layer](https://academic.oup.com/gsmnras/article/2/2/101/640276). He jumps from the Airy Integral to a function containing cosine:

\begin{align} 
Ai(x)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{i\infty}_{-i\infty}e^{\kappa x+\frac{1}{3}\kappa^3}d\kappa \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int^\infty_0\cos(kx-\frac{1}{3}k^3)dk.
\end{align}

I'm a little (a lot) confused by this. Initially I tried writing $e^{f(\kappa)}$ as $\kappa=\alpha+i\beta$, so I'd have something in the form of $re^{i\theta}$ which is  form of the complex number $\kappa$, but this is quite clearly wrong.

I would really like some clarification on how this can be evaluated, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How is $\kappa$ defined? Also have you seen the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function?

Comment: @Zacky $\kappa$ is defined as a complex number. I also hadn't looked at the wiki page, but now that I have I'm even more confused because they define $Ai(x)$ as the integral of $\cos(kx+\frac{1}{3}k^3)$ (ie the negative sign has been changed into a positive). Additionally, there is no mention of how to arrive at this form from the complex integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is such that $\kappa$ is purely imaginary, let $\kappa=ik$.

Then

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{i\infty}_{\kappa=-i\infty}e^{\kappa x+\frac{1}{3}\kappa^3}d\kappa =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\infty}_{k=-\infty}e^{ikx-\frac{1}{3}ik^3}d\kappa.$$

As the complex exponential has an even real part and an odd imaginary part, only the first remains, giving

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{0}\Re\left(e^{ikx-\frac{1}{3}ik^3}\right)d\kappa.$$

Comment: I can see how the cosine function would come out, but do you know how wiki has a positive $\frac{1}{3}k^3$ in the cosine, as opposed to a negative?

Comment: @Fats: just two different definitions.